# How to count the number of lines in a UTF-16LE/CR-LF/BOM file?

Tags: text-processing, unicode, wc

The immediate thought is `wc`, but then the next not-so-immediate thought is... Is *nix's `wc` purely for *nix line endings \x0a?... It seems so.

I've semi-wangled my way around it, but I feel there may/must be a simpler way than working on a hex-dump of the original.

Here is my version, but there is still a mysterious discrepancy in the tallies.  `wc` reports 1 more `0a` than the sum of this script's `CRLF` + `0a`.

```
 file="nagaricb.nag"
 echo Report on CR and LF in UTF-16LE/CR-LF
 echo =====================================
 cat "$file" | # a useles comment, courtesy of cat 
   xxd -p -c 2 |
     sed -nr '
       /0a../{
           /0a00/!{
               i ‾‾`0a:   embedded in non-newline chars       
               b
           }
       }
       /0d../{
           /0d00/!{
               i ‾‾`0d:   embedded in non-newline chars       
               b
           }
       }
       /0a00/{
           i ‾‾`CR: found stray 0a00       
           b
        }
       /0d00/{
           N
           /0d00\n0a00/{
               i ‾‾`CRLF: found as normal newline pairs
               b
           }
           i ‾‾`LF: found stray 0d00
        }' |
         sort |
           uniq -c
 echo "  ====="
 printf '  %s ‾‾`wc\n' $(<"$file" wc -l)
```

Output

```
Report on CR and LF in UTF-16LE/CR-LF
=====================================
    125 ‾‾`0a:   embedded in non-newline chars       
    407 ‾‾`0d:   embedded in non-newline chars       
  31826 ‾‾`CRLF: found as normal newline pairs
  =====
  31952 ‾‾`wc
```

---

Is there some more standard/simple way to do this?

Comment: @Matt: Which version do you have?  I'm using `wc (GNU coreutils) 7.4`

Comment: Way ahead of you :) `wc (GNU coreutils) 8.14`

Comment: @Matt: Have you tried it with unicode chars like \u0a0a `ਊ` or \u090a`ऊ`... That's the only time the problem shows itself...My file has 532 such chars.

Comment: Ah, no those get miscounted. You should count each `0a` that is not "legitimate" I guess, to fix your script. (xx0a doesn't get counted, 0a0a only counts for one, if I understand it correctly).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my script. It works fine. The tally error comes from `wc` (and `awk`'s counting of `NR` is out by a further 1).. the above script's line-count is the same as shown in `emacs`... I'm just trying to find a less clumsy way of counting lines in a UTF-16LE/CR-LF (with BOM, in this case, if that makes a difference) file..

Comment: The fact that you have an off-by-one between your count and wc is, agreed, not a bug in your script, but the difference is (I think) explained by how it works. You're not counting all 0x0a in your script. A perl script could do the count pretty sanely, if you're interested in that.

Comment: Yes... I'm definitely interested...That's exactly the type of thing I'm after... As I mentioned above, the off-by 1 is, *I believe*, on the part of `wc`... `awk` reports an out-by 2 line count... but both `wc` and `awk` ab way off the actual number of `\x0d\x00\x0a\x00` newlines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a perl script that opens files (given as command line arguments) in UTF-16 (endianness detected via BOM), and counts the lines.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $file = shift @ARGV) {
    my $fh;
    if (!open($fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16)', $file)) {
        print STDERR "Failed to open [$file]: $!\n";
        next;
    }
    my $count = 0;
    $count++ while (<$fh>);
    print "$file: $count\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

(Dies if the BOM is not understood.)

Comment: Good, thanks. It works well. I'm still on the outer fringes of perl, so its a good learning example for me. It seems as simple as telling perl to read the file as UTF-16.. I like that... This method has no manipulation of the data (a definite plus), and Warren's method is very simple to write (no scripting is also a definte plus). so both answers are great...

Answer (score 6):

I would convert the file to UTF-8 with LF line endings, so I can directly use the native tools:

```
$ iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 myfile.txt | dos2unix | wc -l
```

The `dos2unix` part is the trickiest bit. There are many variants of this tool floating around, not all of which know how to be used in a pipeline. Sometimes it's called something else, like `d2u`.

Comment: Thanks Waren... I haven't got either `d2u` or `dos2unix` in my Ubuntu repo, but in all this, I've just discovered a similar solution.. It's very much the same, and slightly different, so here it is, for general reference... `<"$file" recode UTF-16LE..UTF-8 |wc -l` ... `recode` uses the `iconv` libraries, and has added the concept of `surfaces` which I'm finding to be quite handy.

Comment: @Peter.O: Really? `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` worked just fine here on my 11.10 box. This version of `dos2unix` works in pipelines. Since `iconv(1)` appears to be installed by default, that should be all you need.

Comment: @Peter.O: I just upgraded that box to 12.04, and `dos2unix` is still in the stock package repo. Then I checked an old stable 8.04 box, and there's not a *package* called `dos2unix`, but there is a package `tofrodos` which includes a `fromdos` command symlinked to `dos2unix`, which works in a pipeline.

Comment: For interest's sake, I just now installed a fresh Ubuntu 11.10 as a VM and `dos2unix` doesn't show up in that defaut system, either... The only tab completion for `dos` is `dosfs`... Oh well, it doesn't matter if the line endings are CR-LF or just LF. for a simple line count, so long as it is UTF-8 (which means that there are no extraneous `\x0a` bytes floating about.

Comment: [It's in the universe repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/dos2unix). Perhaps you have only the main repo enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: **Note/Warning** re `dos2unix`. It became available in 11.10 after my first Update. **However**, reading it's man page, I saw this: `Dos2unix/unix2dos should not be run on UTF-16 files. UTF-16 files are automatically skipped, because they are binary files.`

Answer (score 3):

If you have dos2unix version >= 7.1 you can use the -i option to get information about the number of line breaks. UTF-16 files are also supported. When the file has a BOM dos2unix automatically detects it is UTF-16, LE or BE. When the file has no BOM you can use option -ul to tell it is UTF-16LE (or -ub for UTF-16BE).

dos2unix -i will print the number of DOS, Unix, and Mac line breaks in that order. Example (with BOM):

```
$ dos2unix -i utf16le.txt
      50       0       0  UTF-16LE  text    utf16le.txt
```

Without BOM:

```
$ dos2unix -ul -i utf16len.txt
      50       0       0  no_bom    text    utf16len.txt
```

See the manual for more information.